# Sharepoint 2010 how to export item URL to Excel?

Tags: excel, url, export, sharepoint-library, sharepoint-fields

I have a list of 8 items in SharePoint 2010 and I export them to Excel.  How can I export item's URL so that when clicking the link on Excel spreadsheet, it can bring me back to the item  in SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly , but you can do the following workaround

- At your list View , Make sure that it contains the `ID` of the item.

[image]

[image]

- After you export your list from the ribbon .
- Open excel sheet > and at any column beside your row.
- Add this formula.

> ```
>  =HYPERLINK("https://yourrootsite/Lists/List/DispForm.aspx?ID="&A2,Table_owssvr__2[Title])
> ```

- the output should be like Direct `Linkable link` with a meanning name that is the `title of item`

[image]

- Drag your column down to apply it to all rows Via `+`

Comment: Thanks everyone i was able to solve this with a workflow<

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. It may not have been what the OP wanted, but it worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new calculated field to the list and use formula

```
=CONCATENATE("http://siteurl/lists/listname/forms/displayform.aspx?ID=", Id)
```

Change `siteurl` and `listname`

Now going forward you can simply export the list and no need to update excel file each time.

Comment: Thankyou ! It would be great if i could to that. Ill try it!

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: From List Settings add a new column and select calculated.. Next use the formula I have provided.

Comment: Ok ill try this method then ill let you know. Thankyou again for your help!

Comment: Is the return value of the field single text? I tried on my dev box and its working as expected.

Comment: Do i have to put [ID] before the formula?  i mean [ID]=CONCATENATE("http://MysiteUrl/lists/Mylistname/forms/displayform.aspx?ID=", Id)  . Deos this formula work for a library as I am working with a library not a list?

Comment: No need.. Just understand you are not replacing Id field.. Also your URL doesn't look correct.. It should be like the formula in my answer

Comment: I am still getting the same error . i tried as you said =CONCATENATE("http://mysiteurl/library/libraryname/forms/displayform.aspx?ID=",Mycolonn ID). the return value of the field is single text. its keep one telling me that i might have a syntax error or the comand is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone i was able to solve this with a workflow. I created a new column called Link. Then in the workflow,  I use 3 variables which i called (Url, Link and LinkwithURL). In my workflow i use Set Variable URL at the value of  http://siteurl/lists/listname/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/list/listname[%CurrentItem:yourcolumn%].xml&DefaultItemOpen=1 then set the value of LinkWithUrl at (The colomn i what to get as link) Set the value of LinkWithURL at Variable URL,Variable Link then Set the value of Lien which my new column with the value of LinkwithURl . thats it -----------------